# How to minimise a dependent variable

Tags: python, regression, minimization

I have one dependent variable, three controllable independent variables and eight uncontrollable independent variables. My objective is to determine values of the three controllable independent variables that minimise the dependent variable. (All of my variables are integers.)

Assume that I have already modelled my data using a regression model.

What's the best approach in python?

Comment: Use feature engineering technique like PCA.